# Stimulsoft not work with list Data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, stimulsoft

I write function for make a report in Stimulsoft

```
 public ActionResult Report2()
    {
        Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport rpt = new Stimulsoft.Report.StiReport();
        using (var dbase = new Entities())
        {
            var myCity = dbase.Pub_City.ToList();
            rpt.Load(Server.MapPath("\\report\\city.mrt"));
            rpt.RegData("myCity", myCity);

            if (rpt.RenderedPages.Count == 0)
            {
                rpt.Render(new Stimulsoft.Report.Engine.StiRenderState(true));
            }
            using (System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
            {
                rpt.ExportDocument(Stimulsoft.Report.StiExportFormat.Pdf, ms, settings);
                return File(ms.GetBuffer(), "application/pdf");
            }
        }
    }

    public Stimulsoft.Report.Export.StiPdfExportSettings settings
    {
        get
        {
            Stimulsoft.Report.Export.StiPdfExportSettings _s =
                new Stimulsoft.Report.Export.StiPdfExportSettings
                {
                    EmbeddedFonts = true,
                    UseUnicode = true,
                    ImageResolution = 300
                };
            return _s;
        }
        set { }
    }
```

but when data fetch from database and pass to stimulsoft I don't have any response and finally i receive time out error

what is my mistake ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Move your `dbase.Pub_City.ToList()` to a separate function and then use it here. Don't use its `using` statement for the whole block.
- `RegData` accepts a `DataTable`. Use `RegBusinessObject` to pass a list.
- Also don't use `ms.GetBuffer()`, because it's larger than the original data and contains garbage. Try `ms.ToArray()` instead.
- You can replace your entire export part with just one line: `return StiMvcViewer.ExportReportResult(this.HttpContext);`